# Rewrite a URL to include GET data (with Drupal)

Tags: regex, .htaccess, drupal, url-rewriting, drupal-6

I'm relatively new to both .htaccess and regular expressions, but I really need to do the following. I'm using Drupal for my website (I don't know if the affects anything) but I've wrote a small PHP script that emails a confirmation link to users.

The page that actually processes the link is mysite.com/process?uniqueurl=confirmationLink but I want to be able to email by users the following link mysite.com/reset/confirmationLink.

Could someone give me the code that I need in order to do this? Thanks in advance.

PS: The URLs are obviously not the real ones but they are an accurate representation of my current situation!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^reset/([^/]+) process?uniqueurl=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks a lot. Do you know if Drupal would ever discard that code though?

Comment: I haven't used Drupal but I suppose it should not override this code.

Answer (score 1):

Try the follwing:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^reset/(.*)$ http://mysite.com/process?uniqueurl=$1
```